# create a variable separately but uniquely for each `id` in a data.frame in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, lapply

I have a `data.frame` with two variables `es` and `id`. I want to add a new variable called `weeks`. But I want to create `weeks` separately but uniquely for each `id`.

For example, if `es == "SHORT"` for all rows whose `id == 1`, I want the same number (e.g., `3`). And if `id == 2` a different number (e.g., `1`).

Can I achieve this in **BASE R (*see desired output structure below*)**?

**NOTE:** `SHORT < DEL1 < DEL2` in terms of numerical value under each `id`.

Below is the data and code I tried without success:

```
D <- data.frame(es = c("SHORT", "SHORT", "SHORT","DEL1", "DEL1","DEL1","SHORT", 
            "SHORT", "SHORT", "DEL1", "DEL1", "DEL1","DEL2","DEL2","DEL2"),

                id = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 9)) ) 


weeks <- ifelse(D$es == "SHORT", sample(1:5, 6, T), ifelse(D$es == "DEL1", 
                                                        sample(4:8, 7, T),
                                                        sample(7:12, 2, T)))
```

**Desired output structure (numeric values are random):**

```
   es  id   weeks
SHORT  1     3
SHORT  1     3
SHORT  1     3
 DEL1  1     5
 DEL1  1     5
 DEL1  1     5
SHORT  2     1
SHORT  2     1
SHORT  2     1
 DEL1  2     6
 DEL1  2     6
 DEL1  2     6
 DEL2  2     8
 DEL2  2     8
 DEL2  2     8
```

Comment: Create a lookup data.frame and then use `merge`

Comment: Try `D_lookup <- unique(D); D_lookup$weeks <- c(3, 5, 1, 6, 8); out <- merge(D, D_lookup), out[order(out$id, out$weeks), ]`

Comment: See my updated comment.

Comment: (Just discovered the `sort` argument from `merge`.)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what @markus suggested. Can replace the `seq_along` with `sample` or other function if you need the weeks to be random.

```r
D <- data.frame(es = c("SHORT", "SHORT", "SHORT","DEL1", "DEL1","DEL1","SHORT", 
                       "SHORT", "SHORT", "DEL1", "DEL1", "DEL1","DEL2","DEL2","DEL2"),

                id = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 9)) ) 

weeksTbl <- unique(D)
weeksTbl$weeks <- seq_along(weeksTbl[[1]])

merge(D, weeksTbl, all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)

#>       es id weeks
#> 1  SHORT  1     1
#> 2  SHORT  1     1
#> 3  SHORT  1     1
#> 4   DEL1  1     2
#> 5   DEL1  1     2
#> 6   DEL1  1     2
#> 7  SHORT  2     3
#> 8  SHORT  2     3
#> 9  SHORT  2     3
#> 10  DEL1  2     4
#> 11  DEL1  2     4
#> 12  DEL1  2     4
#> 13  DEL2  2     5
#> 14  DEL2  2     5
#> 15  DEL2  2     5
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider `diff` and `cumsum` for sequential ordering of distinct groupings:

```
set.seed(8132019)
rand <- sample(1:10, 10, replace=FALSE)

D <- within(D, {        
          diff <- c(0,diff(es)) + c(0, diff(id))
          weeks <- cumsum(ifelse(diff == 0, 0, 1)) + 1

          rm(diff)
    })

D
#       es id weeks
# 1  SHORT  1     1
# 2  SHORT  1     1
# 3  SHORT  1     1
# 4   DEL1  1     2
# 5   DEL1  1     2
# 6   DEL1  1     2
# 7  SHORT  2     3
# 8  SHORT  2     3
# 9  SHORT  2     3
# 10  DEL1  2     4
# 11  DEL1  2     4
# 12  DEL1  2     4
# 13  DEL2  2     5
# 14  DEL2  2     5
# 15  DEL2  2     5
```

Comment: Make sure it's ordered by `id` though, or else you could possibly get a `-1` in `diff(id)` cancelling a `1` in `diff(es)` for a diff of 0 (failing to increase the cumsum)

Comment: Good point @IceCreamToucan. Reza, this solution should work in any order of character groups as it checks for differences in two columns: *es* and *id*.

Comment: Actually @IceCreamToucan, I tested with ids of 1 first and then zero and solution still holds: https://rextester.com/GMO24389.

Comment: Original post did not mention ordering but random number grouping. Then just remove the random numbers: `weeks <- cumsum(diff)+1`. See edit.

Comment: Here's an example where ordering is relevant: take the original data, then run `D$id[D$id == 2] <- -1`, then run the `within` code

Comment: Nice edge case, @IceCreamToucan! But OP may not have negative ids.

Comment: Also could happen with all positive ids e.g. it happens with `D$id[D$id == 1] <- 4` instead of the earlier mentioned modification. Anyway, this is a silly edge case I just thought was worth mentioning. Nice solution